# Reset/Reload current form

Tags: c#, forms, reload, reset

I've been trying to reset my current form to it's original state by closing it, and opening a new one. I want the form objects to be reset,the variables to be re-declared, the class objects to be cleared etc I've got everything working but the class being cleared, no matter what I do it won't create a new one with blank data.

Here is my code:

```
if (btnRandom.Text == "Reset")
{

    SetupScreen form = new SetupScreen();
    form.Show();
    this.Dispose();

    //Create new class for form / or launch load events as normal 
    form.Mybattleship = new battleship()
    form.SetupScreen_Load(this, null);
}
```

I've tried many methods over the internet and none have worked.. even the overly complicated ones..

Oh I forgot to mention I need the new form to act as if it's just been loaded as normal, so the load events etc trigger

Comment: Do you mean the `Battleship` class? And is `this` the current instance of `SetupScreen`? If so, creating a `Battleship` there shouldn't be relevant, more info/code would be desirable.

Comment: what would your user be doing to need to close/open a form for a reset exactly? is it not more efficient to reset textbox/variable values?, edit the reason i say this is your pretty much going to face a flicker no matter what you do when switching to the new form

Comment: Well basically I'm creating an electronic version of the Battleship board game 

I want a reset for the SetupScreen so a user can start over again, rather than going through each form object, clearing all the variables etc I want a nice simple way to simply close and re-open a new form

Comment: well consider just making a method for default values that you can call on reset and on load?

Comment: Huh I didn't think of that ^-^ Thanks :D

Comment: no worries :) your original idea was open to other issues such as if you ever wanted to try to add sound, it would stop the sound and start it again from beginning

Comment: Never thought of that, thank you appreciate it :D all this coding is making me a "traditional blonde" got brainrot atm xD

Comment: no worries :) good luck i'll write it as an answer ...

Comment: Thanks, I would answer myself/Vote yours up but low rep :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would be better off making a method that you can call that will set default values for items that you can use when opening form and resetting...

```
public SetupScreen()
{
InitializeComponent();
SetDefaultValues();
}
private void SetDefaultValues()
{
//start  values..
}
public void ResetBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
SetDefaultValues();
}
```